# register_kprobe() returns EINVAL without additional memory on containing struct

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kprobe

I've written a kernel module (a character device) that registers new KProbes whenever I write to the module.

I have a structure that contains `struct kprobe`. When I call `register_kprobe()`, it returns `-EINVAL`. But when I add a dummy character array to the (possibly some other data types as well), the KProbe registration succeeds.

## Probe Registration

```
struct my_struct *container = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
(container->probe).addr = (kprobe_opcode_t *) kallsyms_lookup_name("my_exported_fn"); /* my_exported_fn is in code section */
(container->probe).pre_handler = Pre_Handler;
(container->probe).post_handler = Post_Handler;
register_probe(&container->probe);
/* Returns -EINVAL if my_struct contains only `struct kprobe`. */
```

### Not working:

```
struct my_struct {
     struct kprobe probe;
}
```

### Working:

```
struct my_struct {
     char dummy[512]; /* At 512, it gets consistently registered. At 256, sometimes (maybe one out of 5 - 10 times get registered) */
     struct kprobe probe;
}
```

Why does it need this extra bit of memory to be present in the struct?

Comment: Could you please consider zeroising this chunk of memory before initialising some of its parts? Also, could you please clarify the step "`/* Initialize container->probe with addr, pre_handler and post_handler */`".

Comment: I see your update. You include `memset()` now. So, does it make any difference?

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin Including memset did the trick. Please answer the question, and I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Please find my answer below. Probably, `kzalloc(sizeof(struct my_struct), GFP_KERNEL)` may come in handy in this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *could* be unaligned memory access or not, but in this particular case (I mean your original code before the edit) I suspect that the data is not properly initialised. Namely, `register_kprobe()` [calls](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/kprobes.c#L1534) `kprobe_addr()` function which in turn implies the following [check](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/kprobes.c#L1404):

```
if ((symbol_name && addr) || (!symbol_name && !addr))
    goto invalid;
...
invalid:
    return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);
```

So, if you indeed initialise `addr` and don't initialise `symbol_name`, the latter could be a garbage pointer under certain circumstances. Namely, `kmalloc()` doesn't zeroise allocated memory and, furthermore, depending on requested size, it may take memory object of a suitable size from a different *pool* (there are different *pools* to provide objects of different sizes), and when you artificially increase the size of the struct, `kmalloc()` has to allocate a larger object from a suitable pool. From this perspective, the probability is that such an object *may* not contain garbage by occasion (since larger chunks are requested less often).

All in all, I suggest zeroising the memory chunk or using `kzalloc()`.

Comment: So `kmalloc` can be used for things such as buffer, where we overwrite the data, and `kzalloc` on structs where unexpected things such as this can occur?

Comment: I'd say, yes. If one needs, say, to read some data to the buffer, then memory is allocated with `kmalloc()`, then some code is used to read the data in, say `len = read_some_data(ptr_obtained_by_kmalloc, chunk_size);`, and, if `len < chunk_size`. The caller will know for sure that exactly `len` bytes have been read in, and, of course, this assumes that any garbage within `len` bytes have been overwritten. But if a memory chunk is needed to store some struct and initialise some dedicated fields,  one first needs to make sure that the rest of the data is zero. `kzalloc()` takes care of it.